# how to order three columns at a time which are based on ordering of different column

Tags: mysql

I have below table

```
    category_name      category_order  subcategory_order  startdate   enddate     
    -----------------  --------------  -----------------  ----------  ------------
    Adult                           1             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Fun-Jokes                       6             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Hollywood                       5                  3  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Tollywood                  (NULL)                  2  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Bollywood                  (NULL)                  1  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Movies                          4             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    For Sister                 (NULL)                  3  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    For Dad                    (NULL)                  2  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    For MOM                    (NULL)                  1  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Birthday                        3             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Festivals                       2             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Diwali                     (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-10-01  2017-10-10  
    Holi                       (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-02-15  2017-02-15 
    Christmas                  (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-12-25  2017-12-31  
    Ganapati Festival          (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-08-25  2017-08-31
```

now I want output like this

```
    category_name      category_order  subcategory_order  startdate   enddate     
    -----------------  --------------  -----------------  ----------  ------------
    Adult                           1             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Festivals                       2             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)   
    Ganapati Festival          (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-08-25  2017-08-31     
    Diwali                     (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-10-01  2017-10-10  
    Christmas                  (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-12-25  2017-12-31  
    Holi                       (NULL)             (NULL)  2017-02-15  2017-02-15  
    Birthday                        3             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    For MOM                    (NULL)                  1  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    For Dad                    (NULL)                  2  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    For Sister                 (NULL)                  3  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Movies                          4             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Bollywood                  (NULL)                  1  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Tollywood                  (NULL)                  2  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Hollywood                  (NULL)                  3  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Hollywood                       5             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)      
    Fun-Jokes                       6             (NULL)  (NULL)      (NULL)
```

means I want ordering by category_order in that subcategory order and in subcategory its order by date or if category has date else order by subcategory order numeric 
Note: datewise ordering is based on current date first and remaining later.

Comment: how do you know which `subcategory` belongs to which `category`? I understand it on human Level, but if there is no indication in the table you won't be able to order in a meaningful way

Comment: I have level and parent_id column in my table but i didn't mention it here